# Use Paired T-test or Wilcoxon for this data set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

Question: "Is there a difference in hearing quality between the left and right ears?"

I'm testing for a difference in an interval variable (1-12 scale, hearing quality in each ear) between two paired samples (left ear/right ear).

Both samples have a highly skewed distribution (suggesting Wilcoxon).

However, a histogram of the actual difference on each sample shows a normal distribution (suggesting paired t-test).

There is no specific alternative hypothesis, I've been tasked with applying whichever test I deem more suitable, both seem to fit but is there generally a preference in this situation?

Thanks for any help given,
John

Comment: There's no assumption required for the distribution of the original values; the assumption just relates to the differences (and for the correctness of the significance level, just under H0) ... however, if the original values are simply ordinal, on what basis do you take differences of them -- that is how do you assert that say '6'-'5' = '9'-'8' = '3'-'2' (i.e. that those are all the same size, which you are calling '1'), and that those are all half as big as '11' - '9' or '7'-'5' ... and so on and so forth? All those things together imply you assert an  interval scale, not an ordinal one.

Comment: @Glen_b Ah, I thought that an interval scale and a numerical ordinal scale were synonymous (i'm very much still learning). The differences between each number in the 1-12 scale represent an equal interval. Would this effect your choice of test in this scenario?

Comment: Both tests treat the measured variable as interval (numeric), because the first step in each involves subtracting the values. ...  The expected answer probably depends on how the course is presenting this material.  I suspect that the material is presented as, "if the t-test is appropriate, use that.  If not, use Wilcoxon".  I think that's not a good way to present different tests, but it's common.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag to the question, and see the guidelines here: [stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: @SalMangiafico Noted and edited. Certainly we've been told that parametric tests are more powerful so presumably if it's possible then we should use them. ///// Though it seems that any 2 samples of interval data with similar skewed distributions would present a normally distributed histogram of differences. ////// So I feel like there must be something i'm not aware of preventing the paired t-test being used here

Comment: It's impossible to know what you're supposed to conclude given the context of the course, but it's possible the idea is test students if they know to look at the distribution of the differences rather than the distributions of the left and right groups.

Comment: "Certainly we've been told that parametric tests are more powerful" ... stated as a general claim, this is not the case. Parametric tests *that are chosen to be the most powerful for some set of assumptions* - and  a specific alternative hypothesis - are naturally going to be hard to beat, but in many cases a *well-chosen* nonparametric test *of that same hypothesis* can do as well in large samples. That is, even when you rig the game to favor parametric tests, the best they can do in large samples is about as good as a corresponding nonparametric test . . . ctd

Comment: . . . ctd The problem is you never know that the assumptions are actually true and then a more generic form of nonparametric test may heavily beat the parametric one *on the parametric tests specific hypothesis* for many possible situations outside those original assumptions. In some common cases, the assumptions only need to be a *little* bit off and the parametric test suffers by comparison. Which is to say, in practice (where you don't know your assumptions are true), the parametric tests may easily have *worse* power, not better. "*Parametric tests are more powerful*" needs context to hold

Comment: @John-Nottingham "The differences between each number in the 1-12 scale represent an equal interval." If you know they do this, why would you call it an ordinal scale? You just clearly stated it to be an interval scale. (How do you know, by the way, that the gaps are the same size?)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks that's enlightening, we'd been told it unequivocally. I was confused about the distinction so edited my original question. We've been told to treat each interval as equal as part of the question.